# Convert ModalDialog to DialogBox

Tags: google-apps-script

In my apps script for Google Docs I'm trying to convert a ModalDialog to a DialogBox so that I can take advantage of the addCloseHandler() on DialogBoxes.

My showModalDialog works with the following GS code:

```
function showSheetPicker() {
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sheetPicker').evaluate().
                setHeight(400).setWidth(600);
   DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Select a Sheet");
}
```

However, when I tried converting that to use createDialogBox(), I came up with the following:

```
function showSheetPicker() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();
    var autoHide = false;
    var modal = true;
    var dialog = app.createDialogBox(autoHide, modal);
    dialog.setPopupPosition(100, 100).setSize(650, 450).setHTML(html)
      .setTitle("Select a Sheet").createCloseHandler(handlingTheClose).show();
    return app;
  }
```

This is producing an error that tells me: `The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type..`

What would I need to do to convert my ModalDialog to a DialogBox so that I can take advantage of the addCloseHandler()?

Comment: Thanks, @Sergeinsas. I edited my question to mention that I'm using Google Docs, I should have clarified that before. It seems that DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() doesn't have a show(). I did try using  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(app, "title"), but that just put a Dialog on my ModalDialog. And the Dialog only said, "HTMLOutput".

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I deleted my comment as well ;-) There was actually a simple showDialog method but it's deprecated. Not sure one can do what you want, I'll keep searching and let you know if I find something.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a doc showing a dialogBox but the result is quite disappointing...

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var autoHide = false;
  var modal = true;
  var dialog = app.createDialogBox(autoHide, modal);
  dialog.setPopupPosition(100, 100).setSize(650, 450)
  .setTitle('hover me').setHTML('this is a test dialog');
  app.add(dialog).setHeight(450).setWidth(650);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(app, "Select a Sheet")
}
```

I've never succeeded in using this widget... good luck.

As for the closeHandler, I doubt you can use it since you won't be able to close the inner dialogBox, you will actually close the ModelessDialog in this example... (good luck again... I give up ;-)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @sergeinsas! Basically, what I'm doing is starting a poll process that is checking for a specific value in the Properties. I can set that value when the user clicks either the Save or Close buttons in the ModalDialog. My one situation that isn't accounted for is when the user clicks the X on the ModalDialog. Can you think of another way to approach this what wouldn't require a CloseHandler?

Comment: I understand the issue... unfortunately I don't have any solution except checking the properties value systematically using a hover trigger on the main Ui element itself... (not even sure it works, just a suggestion).